# Accounting for occasionally correlated data in performance analysis

Tags: model-evaluation, independence, agreement-statistics

I'm doing a study in which a new diagnostic method is evaluated. Samples are taken from patients, both this new method and the current standard method are applied, and we calculate concordance between the methods. The problem is that some of the samples are from the same patient, and are thus highly correlated. I would simply use each patient only once if it weren't for the fact that despite the similarity both tests occasionally produce different results for different samples from the same patient. This seems like meaningful information that I would rather not throw away.

Ideally I'm looking for a standard method to deal with this, which I have not been able to find. If there is no good method I can simply discard all-but-the-first sample for each patient, but that would be a shame.

Most patients only have one sample, but multiple is common enough that discarding duplicates would be a significant waste.

Comment: How are you going to calculate concordance from the participants for whom you only have one observation? If I understand what concordance is it is only the ones with both methods applied which are relevant.

Comment: @mdewey The concordance in the study is between two different diagnostic methods, both of which work on single samples. Each sample has been diagnosed using both methods.